# How do you know lengths PC and PB are equal in this diagram?

Tags: geometry

In the image seen here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3Jn.jpg
if you draw the PA, you have two isosceles triangles because PB=PC=PA. I do not understand why PB=PC though, can somebody explain?

This comes from an SAT question which I have the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

Both $PB$ and $PC$ are radii of the circle, just as $PA$ is.